# Плавность скрола JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Эсть скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("a[href*=#]").on("click", function(e){ 
var anchor = $(this); 
$('html, body').stop().animate({ 
scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top 
}, 777); 
e.preventDefault(); 
return false; 
}); 
}); 
});
```

Но в jQuery 3.2.1 не работает плавность, на какое значение можно поменять, что бы бил плавный скрол?
или может кто знает как по другому можно сделать?

Comment: или может кто знает как по другому можно сделать?

Comment: зачем у Вас 2 раза $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: Можна без него, я с форума скопировал

Comment: А код html почему не скопировали? Без него вообще непонятно, что и как скроллится

Comment: Так етоуниверсальный скрипт, и суть в том что скролится нормально только оно резко нет анимации а в jQuery 3.2.1 отменили свойство отвечающе за анимация плавности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, jQuery, начиная с версии 2.2.4, ругается на конструкцию $('a[href*=#]'). Так что вешайте клик просто на $('a'):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("a").on("click", function(e){ 
var anchor = $(this); 
$('html, body').stop().animate({ 
scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top 
}, 777); 
e.preventDefault(); 
return false; 
}); 
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a>
<a href="#two">two</a>
<a href="#three">three</a>

<div id="one">
ONE
</div>

<div id="two">
TWO
</div>

<div id="three">
THREE
</div>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```